# how we can bind a list of a list of object using thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a form where the user can add as much as he want of **Table object** that also can contains as much as he want of **Columns object** (like building tables in SQL).. I've tried the code bellow but nothing works and the form dosnt appear anymore when I've tried to bind the two lists.

**Controller**

```
@ModelAttribute("page")
    public Page getTable() {
         TableColumn column = new TableColumn();
            List<TableColumn> columns = new ArrayList<>();
            columns.add(column);

            Table table = new Table();
            table.setColumns(columns);

            List<Table> tables = new ArrayList<>();
            tables.add(table);

            Page page = new Page();
            page.setTables(tables);
        return page;
    }


    @GetMapping("/scriptsqlgenerator")
    public String viewForm(@ModelAttribute("page") Page page) {
        return "ScriptSqlNext";
    }

    @PostMapping("/scriptsqlgenerator")
    public String generateScript(@ModelAttribute("page") Page page) {
    page.tables.forEach((t) ->{
    System.out.println(t.getName());
        t.getColumns().forEach((c) -> {
        System.out.println(c.getName());
        System.out.println(c.getType());
        System.out.println(c.getIndex());
        System.out.println(c.getNotnull());
        });
    });
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<form th:object="${page}" class="list-group" th:action="@{/filegenerated}" method="get">
<a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#target1"> Create Table </a>
    <div id="target1" class="collapse" style="margin: 30px;">
        <div id="tablelist">
            <div class="form-inline itemtable" th:each="table, itemStat :${page.tables}">
                <div class="form-group mb-2 d-none">
                   <input th:field="*{tables[__${itemStat.index}__].id}" type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mb-2">
                    <input th:field="*{tables[__${itemStat.index}__].name}" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Table name">
                </div>
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger mb-2 ml-2" onclick="addRow()" value="Add column">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col" class="d-none">Id</th>
                            <th scope="col">Column Name</th>
                            <th scope="col">Type</th>
                            <th scope="col">Index</th>
                            <th scope="col">Null</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="columnlist">
                        <tr class="item" th:each="column,status : 
                            ${table.columns}">
                            <td><input th:field="*{tables[__${itemStat.index}__].columns[__${status.index}__].name}" type="text" class="form-control" required></td>
                            <td><select th:field="*{tables[__${itemStat.index}__].columns[__${status.index}__].type}" id="inputState" class="form-control" required>
                                <option value="" selected 
                                 disabled>Choose</option>
                                <option th:value="${type}">int</option>
                                <option th:value="${type}">varchar</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td><select th:field="*{tables[__${itemStat.index}__].columns[__${status.index}__].index}" id="inputState" class="form-control" required>
                                <option value="" selected 
                                 disabled>Choose</option>
                                <option th:value="${index}">on</option>
                                <option th:value="${index}">off</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td><select th:field="*{tables[__${itemStat.index}__].columns[__${status.index}__].notnull}" id="inputState" class="form-control" required>
                                <option value="" selected 
                                 disabled>Choose</option>
                                <option th:value="${notnull}">on</option>
                                <option th:value="${notnull}">off</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <button class="btn btn-danger mb-2 text-center" type="button" id="addTable" style="margin-top: 30px;">Add table</button>
</div>

<div class="text-center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-lg" style="margin- 
     top: 50px;">Generate File</button>
</div>
</form>
```

**For the JS part I was using some codes to implement the `addRow()` method which will add more Columns to the Table and `addTable()` method that would add another Table object, but nothing was working for my case**

**This is my view is looking like**:
[image]
***PLEASE CAN ANYONE HELP ME TO SOLVE THAT .. I REALLY NEED IT .... ***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is okay. But you need to fix a few things.

In the `getTable` method, you are setting empty lists for `tables` and `columns`. So there is nothing to iterate over in the view layer to show the form. Change to:

```
@ModelAttribute("page")
public Page getTable() {
    Column column = new Column();
    List<Column> columns = new ArrayList<>();
    columns.add(column);

    Table table = new Table();
    table.setColumns(columns);

    List<Table> tables = new ArrayList<>();
    tables.add(table);

    Page page = new Page();
    page.setTables(tables);

    return page;
}
```

#### And

Add missing `}` for `th:field="*{tables[__${i.index}__].name"` and close this `input` tag.

**NOTE:**
I am not sure how you wanted to handle the three `select` inputs. I tested omitting them, meaning, keeping only `Column` `id` and `name` in the form, data bind without any issue in that case.

Also I didn't check your `JS`, as you have mentioned that you haven't tested it yet.

**Suggestions:**

I see you are returning a view name from your `POST` handler. Take a look at the following article on Wikipedia.

[**Post/Redirect/Get**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer I really appreciate it. Actually my objective is to create a form where the user can enter Tables Names and each table can contains multiple columns so thereafter I can generate the SQL script of what he need (like the `CREATE TABLE` query ).. I will edit my post so it would be more clear

Comment: @SarahAbouyassine you are welcome. Btw, you removed the JS code while editing. About adding new tables and/or columns, i would suggest you do that from backend. Send a req to the controller, add an object to the list inside the command object and return the view.

Comment: Yeah its a good idea but I don't have to refresh the page so I have to implement them using JS or ajax

Comment: @SarahAbouyassine if you want to use AJAX, i think you don't need to populate the command object in GET. You can generate the form (without any command) with JS and then collect user provided data and send them to a controller with AJAX. I think that should be a different question than this one as this one was mainly about data-binding.

Comment: Yes exactly .. Now I'm binding the data successfuly.. I'm working now on the JS part and how i can keep the fields name for the new rows created, and thats not the subject of my question here.. Thank you for all.

Comment: @SarahAbouyassine You are most welcome. Hope you will get the job done successfully. Stay safe!