# Is there anyway to bind a list of list object using thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a list of tables and every Table has a list of columns.
Can I bind the list of columns using `th:field`?

Table class has attributes `String name`, `List of columns`

Column class has attribute `String name`, `String type`, `String index`, `String notnull`.

Comment: If you have a list of list you may want to render a HTML table that contains HTML tables? Or don't I understand your question?

Comment: I'm using a form where we can add a **Table name** then for this table we can add as much as we want of **Columns object**.
then we can add another **Table object** with other **Columns object** ....

Comment: As I said this is a table of tables

Comment: Yes if we can say .. it's a list of Tables that contains Columns

Comment: I tried to put my code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61952183/how-we-can-bind-a-list-of-a-list-of-object-using-thymeleaf) but I don't know if its clear enough or I should clarify my situation more